# Android delay check for update recursive

Tags: android, recursion, delay

I believe I might be attacking this problem with the wrong method or I'm not correctly coding it.  I getting to many calls for an update. Sometimes I get update check several in hour.  This function is my update function that calls to check for an update every so often unless there no internet and delays and tries again four hours.  I don't know if I'm going about this right using a delay?  I need for the update function to check and recheck every 24 hours regardless if it finds an update or not.  It must try every 24 hours unless it doesn't have internet on the 24th hour and should try again in 4 hours. Am doing this correctly?

```
private final Runnable mUpdateUI = new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run()
        {
            if (isNetworkAvailable()== true)
            {
                try 
                    {
                        new checkupdate().execute();
                         mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateUI, 86400000);
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Daily update check!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
            else
                {
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateUI, 21600000);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No internet for Daily update check, try again in little!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

        }

    }
```

;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private Handler mHandler;
private int delayTime;
private final Runnable mUpdateUi = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        check();
    }

};

private void start(){
    new Thread(
        new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                Looper.prepare();
                mHandler = new Handler();
                check();
                Looper.loop();
            }
        }
    ).run();
}


private void check(){
    if (isNetworkAvailable()== true){
        try {
            new checkupdate().execute();
            delayTime = 86400000;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Daily update check!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            delayTime = 21600000;
        }
    }else{
        delayTime = 21600000;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No internet for Daily update check, try again in little!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    reCheck()
}

private void reCheck(){
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateUI, delayTime);
}
```

If you don't want this to run in background, just skip the new Thread() part. This way all you need to do is call start() once and voila!

Comment: If call on this as I am doing now with my original code in the onCreate function, can that be problem?  Wouldn't each time i come from resume or closing of the program that it will call the update function and now I will two or three...etc update functions running background.  Ideally this will check ONCE every 24 hours.  So where do I call this then? or do I need some kinda of catch to check if it is already running?

Comment: I previously call on this from onCreate using this command.        mHandler.post(mUpdateUI);  So use start() instead?  I was thinking about moving this code to another class, would that be problem?

Comment: I get an error with your Looper, it saids that it can only run one looper at a time.  I can't start the app or it wont' inflate the main activity. I am running another handler and runnable for another function. What should I do?  I didn't have this issue before.

Comment: The looper part will give you error if you dont call It from a new Thread. If this task is for updating data I recommend you to get It out of the activity and put It inside an intent Service because, as you said, this Would be restarted when your activity but may also be destroyed as well with it

Comment: I'm trying to put your code into a service if you get change maybe help me out on another post. Thanks either way! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212986/android-intentservice-update-loop