# Android IntentService update loop

Tags: android, updates, intentservice

My intention is to have download service created when the app first runs and checks for update every 24 hours.  I originally had everything running my main activity but it seems to much to run everything on one thread and one class.  So this is my attempt to move it to another class and into service.  It suppose to run and check for an update ever 24 hours and if there is no internet try again in 4 hours.  I specifically want to involve any recursive problems, having two or three same services checking update, just one every 24 hours. But having problem with integrating my code into service, what am I doing wrong?

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {

// TODO 0 - Define your Download Service as Android component in
// AndroidManifest.xml
private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;

public DownloadService() {
    super("DownloadService");
}

// Will be called asynchronously be Android
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    private final Runnable mUpdateUi = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            check();
        }

    };

    private void start(){
       new Thread(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    Log.d(TAG, "inside start");
                    Looper.prepare();
                    mHandler = new Handler();
                    check();
                    Looper.loop();
                }
            }
        ).run();
    }


    private void check(){
        if (isNetworkAvailable()== true){
            try {
                new checkupdate().execute();
                delayTime = 86400000;
                Toast.makeText(DownloadService.this, "Daily update check!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                delayTime = 21600000;
            }
        }else{
            delayTime = 21600000;
            Toast.makeText(DownloadService.this, "No internet for Daily update check, try again in little!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        reCheck();
    }

    private void reCheck(){
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateUi, delayTime);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IntentService` already handles setting up a worker thread and queue, and termination when the queue is empty. Which makes it a very good candidate for something like a download service to manage the actual work of downloading data, but not really a great candidate for a time scheduler.

I'd suggest using an [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule your work instead. What you want is to trigger an Intent to start your DownloadService, by sending it intent with an Action indicating what to do.

Note also that if you want to **cancel** an IntentService with an Action, you will need to implement onStartCommand in addition to the usual onHandleIntent, so that you can respond to the action immediately -- you cannot do this from onHandleIntent, since the intent won't be sent to that until the current task in the queue is completed. Here's a quick example:

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "DownloadService";

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Actions

    public static final String ACTION_CANCEL   = "package.name.DownloadService.action.CANCEL";
    public static final String ACTION_DOWNLOAD = "package.name.DownloadService.action.DOWNLOAD";

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Broadcasts

    public static final String BROADCAST_DOWNLOADED = "package.name.DownloadService.broadcast.DOWNLOADED";
    public static final String BROADCAST_ERROR      = "package.name.DownloadService.broadcast.ERROR";

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Extras

    public static final String MESSAGE = "package.name.DownloadService.extra.MESSAGE";
    // etc.

    private boolean isCancelled;

    // usual stuff omitted

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(intent != null) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand() - action: "+action);
            if(ACTION_CANCEL.equals(action)) {

                isCancelled = true;

                // insert code here to signal any objects to cancel
                // their work, etc.

                stopSelf();
            }
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if(intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.v(TAG, "onHandleIntent() - action: "+action);
            if(ACTION_DOWNLOAD.equals(action)) {
                handleDownloading(intent);
            }
            else if(ACTION_CANCEL.equals(action)) {
                // nothing to do here, handled in onStartCommand
            }
        }
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private void handleDownloading(Intent intent) {

        // get stuff you need from the intent using intent.getStringExtra(), etc.

        if(!isCancelled) {
            // do downloading, call broadcastDownloaded() when done
        }
        else {
            // stop work, send broadcast to report cancellation, etc.
        }
    }

    // send a broadcast to a BroadcastReceiver (e.g. in your activity)
    // to report that the download completed
    private void broadcastDownloaded() {
        Log.v(TAG, "broadcastDownloaded()");
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        if (broadcastIntent != null) {
            broadcastIntent.setAction(BROADCAST_DOWNLOADED);
            broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }
    }

    private void broadcastError(String message) {
        Log.v(TAG, "broadcastError(), message: "+message);
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        if (broadcastIntent != null) {
            broadcastIntent.setAction(BROADCAST_ERROR);
            broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            if(message != null) {
                broadcastIntent.putExtra(MESSAGE, message);
            }
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This very interesting and thank you for your response!  I'm currently sending my downloads to the Download manager, would you still brother using intent service then?  I couldn't scrap the idea of the intent service and just use the alarm manager to trigger the checkupdate on 24 hour period and then send my downloads like usual to download manger?

Comment: If you're using `android.app.DownloadManager` then no, you don't need to use an IntentService with that. About the only reason to use your own IntentService with it would be to have some other task performed immediately before calling the DownloadManager -- since IntentService implements a work queue, it can be a convenient way to chain tasks. Based on what you've described, though, I don't see any need for it in this case. DownloadManager already does what your custom IntentService would need to do, in a more robust and flexible way.

Comment: "...you will need to implement onStartCommand in addition to the usual onHandleIntent..." - Thank you. I've been struggling to update my `IntentService` action.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how `IntentService` is meant to be used. As per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), `IntentService` already creates its own worker threads. You should not be creating your own:

> Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

Apart from the fact that your code as shown here won't compile (your `start` method is inside the `onHandleIntent` method), your general approach seems to be to start your own worker thread. What would happen in this approach is that you would start the thread, `onHandleIntent` would complete and then the service would be stopped. In addition to not actually working, this approach is also a bad idea because (at best if you're lucky) the service would be running continually 24/7.

What you should do instead is actually do your main work in `onHandleIntent` which `IntentService` will queue on a worker thread for you. Then instead of using `postDelayed` use [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to set an alarm to send an `Intent` to start the service again in 24 hours or 4 hours.

Comment: So should I call on the service to do my update work?  So the purpose of me running this code in service was because I was having problems running it on the same main thread with other runnables or handlers.  So I don't know what to do now? Here is my original posting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184419/android-delay-check-for-update-recursive/22184754?noredirect=1#22184754